# Task dependency order in Ant

Tags: java, ant

I am trying to learn ant and found an [example build file](https://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html) in the docs.

```
<project name="MyProject" default="dist" basedir=".">
  <description>
    simple example build file
  </description>
  <!-- set global properties for this build -->
  <property name="src" location="src"/>
  <property name="build" location="build"/>
  <property name="dist" location="dist"/>

  <target name="init">
    <!-- Create the time stamp -->
    <tstamp/>
    <!-- Create the build directory structure used by compile -->
    <mkdir dir="${build}"/>
  </target>

  <target name="compile" depends="init"
        description="compile the source">
    <!-- Compile the java code from ${src} into ${build} -->
    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}"/>
  </target>

  <target name="dist" depends="compile"
        description="generate the distribution">
    <!-- Create the distribution directory -->
    <mkdir dir="${dist}/lib"/>

    <!-- Put everything in ${build} into the MyProject-${DSTAMP}.jar file -->
    <jar jarfile="${dist}/lib/MyProject-${DSTAMP}.jar" basedir="${build}"/>
  </target>

  <target name="clean"
        description="clean up">
    <!-- Delete the ${build} and ${dist} directory trees -->
    <delete dir="${build}"/>
    <delete dir="${dist}"/>
  </target>
</project>
```

I'm assuming the `clean` step should run before the `init` step however neither step depends on the other. Should `init` depend on `clean` step? If not, how does ant know the proper order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When this ant build file runs, the clean target will not be executed.  It isn't in the dependency chain.  You would have to explicitly trigger it form the command line, e.g.

```
ant -f _buildFile.xml clean
ant -f _buildFile.xml
```

I've done that within a bash file.  This is an example file, though, so it isn't necessarily how your final build system will work.

Maybe doing a *dist* should do *clean* first (seems reasonable), but that should be part of the *dist* dependencies, not the *init* target.  For instance, you might want to compile and not do a *clean*.  So

```
<target name="dist" depends="clean, compile"...
```

Or you could add a new target, *clean_dist*, for instance and add the dependency there.  Then you could do a quick distribution build and real distribution build by specifying the target on the command line.